# Choose your own adventure book series, including one about an alien invasion, where I think you board the ship to try and beat them

Tags: story-identification, books, choose-your-own-adventure

I'm trying to find a series of choose your own adventure books. From what I can remember, they were standalone and the ones I have memory of are:

1. You're a knight exploring a cave/dungeon looking for treasure/a gem, I think I remember a cat being one of the options that led to a bad ending, I think there might've been a fight with a dragon as well but don't quote me on that.
2. An alien invasion where I think you board the ship to try and beat them.
3. Very vague, but I think one of the books in the series had a jungle, but that's all I remember.

These aren't in any particular order, but I think there are only 4 books in the series, at least that was the case when I read them back in 2016 and my school never had the 4th one. If they've made more, I'd love to know, but for the life of me I can't remember anything about it.

Comment: [Starship Warrior](https://gamebooks.org/Item/3590/Show)?

Comment: [Captain's Choice](https://gamebooks.org/Item/3864/Show)?

Comment: [Inside UFO 54-40](https://gamebooks.org/Item/554/Show)?

Comment: @Valorum It’s a series of four - was UFO 54-40 expanded into a series?

Answer (score 4):

Now I know why I was so confused! I wasn't actually looking for one series I was looking for two published as [EDGE books](https://www.amazon.co.uk/stores/page/00A64FD5-1058-424A-ADA5-215DED264E33). The ones I was looking for were [*You Choose If You Live or Die*](https://simonsjungle.co.uk/index.php/series/live-or-die/) and [*I HERO Blood Crown Quests*](https://www.hachette.co.uk/?s=blood%20crown%20quest).

[*You Choose If You Live or Die: Alien Invasion*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23911839-edge)

> Strange objects have been appearing across the Earth, and then people start disappearing. The aliens are coming, and they don't want to make peace. They're here to kill us all!
> This book isn't like others you may have read - inside you make the choices.
> Can you help to stop the alien invasion? Can you save the human race? Only you can decide if you live or die inside!

The Blood Crown Quest books can be found [here](https://www.goodreads.com/series/122030-edge-i-hero-blood-crown-quests).

> We dare you to take on the Red Queen in this choose-your-own-destiny Blood Crown Quest! The Red Queen has seized the Ruby of Death and raised an army of the dead. Now, with her husband, the necromancer Mortha, they plan to find the remaining three rubies and cast a permanent shadow over the world. YOU are a former City Guard, a member of an elite unit of highly trained warriors. YOUR quest is to find the four Blood Crown rubies, and use them to defeat the Red Queen and her evil forces.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to provide a bit more info on the specific books you had in mind, such as the individual titles, authors, publication dates, and ideally some story details as well. Feel free to quote text from sites such as Goodreads or Amazon, and please provide links to any pages you do quote text from.